# Как обновить список spinner в android?

Tags: android

Есть activity(конвертер валют):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В данном примере основная валюта "TJS".
Для удобства я в spinner 2 по ум. установил "TJS", и сделал так, что когда в любом из 2х спиннеров выбирается "TJS", spinner становиться неактивным.

Есть imagebutton, который меняет позиции у spinner-ов.

Чего хочу я достичь в этом примере:
Мне необходимо скрыть или удалить из одного spinner-а Item c "TJS", если во втором spinner-е уже выбран(установлен) "TJS".

Я попытался удалит item c помощью remove, и он удаляется, но как заново добавить(обновить) в spinner "TJS", потому как при нажатии Imagebutton "TJS" должен установиться в 1-ом spinner-е, а во втором уже не должно быть "TJS"?

Надеюсь понятно изложил суть вопроса...)

Comment: Не совсем понятна суть. Но если удаляется с помощью ``remove``, то добавить можно с помощью ``add``.

Comment: @Эникейщик - да, вы правы, не уточнил, с помощью remove я удаляю из массива jsonobjet, но вот потом, как мне заново обновить spinner c добавленным объектом...

Comment: ``spinner.add("TJC");               spinnerArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`` - как-то так.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас 2 spinner, которые зависят друг-друга, и они должны быть сихронизированы. Любая синхронизация, даже такая простая приводит к дополнительным сложностям (корнер  кейсам), которые лучше не создавать.

1. Самый простой способ дать пользователю конверитровать одинаковые валюту. Я например в этом ничего страшного не вижу, особенно если появится одинаковая валюта с разными курсами, тогда вы сможете различить разницу (банк/биржа). Для этого ничего не надо городить.
2. Другой способ, это не изменять data-layer (тем более вы там ещё с JonObject играетесь), а запомниать выбранные элементы (adapter.setCheckedValue), и вызывать notify для адаптера. А уже в адаптере, при bind holder, скрывать эту ячейку, тогда вы не будете играться с data, что тоже может привести к интересным кейсам. Более того вы 1 раз пропишите логику и у вас будет всегда работать, даже если произошел асинхрон, в адаптерах.
3. Считаю самым плохим. Это делать чтот-тип того.

   ```
   spinnerArrayAdapter.add("TJC"); 
   spinnerArrayAdapter2.remove("TJC");
   spinnerArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
   spinnerArrayAdapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
   ```